# Subspace $U\subset U^{\perp}$ has dimension at most $n/2$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, bilinear-form

We have $V$ a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of finite dimension $n$ with non-degenerate bilinear form $\phi:V\times V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and subspace $U$ of $V$ with $U\subset U^{\perp}$. How do I show that the dimension of $U$ is at most $n/2$?

Edit $U^{\perp}=\{v\in V:\phi(v,u)=0\space \forall u\in U\}$

Comment: Hmm, I thought $U\cap U^{\perp} = \{0\}$ for any set $U$?

Comment: Presumably, $U^{\perp}$ is defined here in terms of the bilinear form, and not the usual dot product. @MPW

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You are right

Comment: Is your bilinear form symmetric - that is - if $\phi(v,w)=\phi(w,v)$? If not, you are going to need to define $U^{\perp}$ specifically. It would also help to be specific about what you mean by "degenerate." I'm taking it to mean that $\phi$ isn't zero everywhere, but I don't know.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Not (necessarily) symmetric, see edit

Comment: What does non-degenerate mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That $\phi(v,v)>0$ for all v and equals 0 iff v=0

Comment: if $\phi(v,v)>0$ for all $v$, then $U^{\perp}$ can never contain $U$ beyond the trivial $U=\{0\}$. So that can't be what the question means. @LucasGeorge

Answer (score 0):

Non-degenerate means in this case that the linear map

$$V  \rightarrow V^\ast; \quad v \mapsto \phi(v, \cdot)$$

is an isomorphism. Under this isomprphism, the subspace $U^\perp$ is isomprphic to what we call the *anihilator* of $U$ in $V^\ast$, i.e.  the subspace $U' := \lbrace v^\ast \in V^\ast \, |\, v^\ast(u) = 0 \quad \forall u \in U \rbrace$ of $V^\ast$.

Now choose a basis $(u_1, \dots, u_k, w_{k+1}, \dots, w_n)$ of $V$ such that $(u_1, \dots, u_k)$ is a basis of $U$. Let $(u_1^\ast,\dots, u_k^\ast, w_{k+1}^\ast,  \dots, w_n^\ast)$ be its dual basis in $V^\ast$. Then $(w_{k+1}^\ast, \dots, w_n^\ast)$ is a basis of $U'$. The assumption $U \subset U^\perp \cong U'$ then implies that 
$$k = \dim{U} \leq \dim{U^\perp} =\dim{U'} = n-k$$
which is equivalent to $k \leq \frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: Is this answer unclear, Lucas?